# xsl prioritized configuration files

Tags: xml, xslt, sequence, configuration-files

Ultimately, I need to create a convenient way to read multiple configuration files for controlling the processing of a complex xsl transformation (2.0, currently).  Each configuration file may or may not have particular nodes.  A relative priority exists between the configuration files, and the ultimate value for any particular value should come from the highest priority configuration file in which the value exists.

A simple configuration file (so.xml) with one variable is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="urn:config.template.config" >
    <primary>Yes, this is primary</primary>
</config>
```

**Old Method:** I read one file by setting a parameter to the value "primary" in a single configuration file for a node "primary":

```
<xsl:param name="primary" select="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/myConfig:primary/text()"/>
```

**Now:** I may have up to four configuration files that *may* have "primary" as a value.  To do this, I chose to write two templates.  `pickConfigNode` is to search in the template files (using a select to do the prioritizing of the read) to see if the requested node with the value contained in 'level1'.

```
<xsl:template name="pickConfigNode">
    <xsl:param name="level1"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$secondaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This works sufficiently well enough for me *as long as the value exists in some configuration file* (shown with searching primary and secondary).  However, it is possible that the value is not defined anywhere.  I think I would like an empty sequence to be returned which is what happens if the node does not exist with the **old method**.  However, I maybe misunderstanding something about how the '*' works when nothing is found.

`pickConfigNode` returns a partial document.  So, this leads to problems with `pickConfigText`:

```
<xsl:template name="pickConfigText" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="level1"/>

    <xsl:variable name="chosenNode">
        <xsl:call-template name="pickConfigNode">
            <xsl:with-param name="level1" select="$level1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$chosenNode/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the secondary file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="urn:config.template.config" >
    <onlySecondary>from secondary</onlySecondary>
    <primary>No, this is secondary</primary>
</config>
```

Here is the complete test case that uses the two configuration files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:myConfig="urn:config.template.config"
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="myConfig xs"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="us-ascii" cdata-section-elements="p i b u li"/>

    <xsl:variable name="configFile" select="'so.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="primaryConfig" select="document($configFile)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="secondaryConfig" select="document('second.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template name="pickConfigNode">
        <xsl:param name="level1"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]">
                <xsl:value-of select="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$secondaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="pickConfigText" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="level1"/>

        <xsl:variable name="chosenNode">
            <xsl:call-template name="pickConfigNode">
                <xsl:with-param name="level1" select="$level1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$chosenNode/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:param name="primary">
        <xsl:call-template name="pickConfigText">
            <xsl:with-param name="level1" select="'primary'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="onlySecondary">
        <xsl:call-template name="pickConfigText">
            <xsl:with-param name="level1" select="'onlySecondary'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="neither">
        <xsl:call-template name="pickConfigText">
            <xsl:with-param name="level1" select="'neither'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PRIMARY>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$primary"><SUCCESS><xsl:value-of select="$primary"/></SUCCESS></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FAILURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'No value for primary'"/>
                    </FAILURE>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </PRIMARY>
        <SECONDARY>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$onlySecondary"><SUCCESS><xsl:value-of select="$onlySecondary"/></SUCCESS></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FAILURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'No value for onlySecondary'"/>
                    </FAILURE>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </SECONDARY>
        <NEITHER>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($neither)"><SUCCESS>NOT in either file</SUCCESS></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FAILURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Got value of for neither='"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$neither"/>
                    </FAILURE>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </NEITHER>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<PRIMARY>
   <SUCCESS>Yes, this is primary</SUCCESS>
</PRIMARY>
<SECONDARY>
   <SUCCESS>from secondary</SUCCESS>
</SECONDARY>
<NEITHER>
   <FAILURE>Got value of for neither=</FAILURE>
</NEITHER>
```

So, I want the NEITHER result to be "SUCCESS".

Your help in helping me understand my misconception of xslt processing is appreciated.  Also, if you have an alternative approach to handling prioritized configuration files, I would be eager to hear that also.

Comment: Good question. There exists a generalized technique of getting a config value from the highest-priority file when **any number** of config files are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ultimately, I need to create a convenient way to read multiple
>   configuration files for controlling the processing of a complex xsl
>   transformation (2.0, currently). Each configuration file may or may
>   not have particular nodes. A relative priority exists between the
>   configuration files, and the ultimate value for any particular value
>   should come from the highest priority configuration file in which the
>   value exists.

**Here is a general technique to extract values from multiple files according to their predefined priority**:

Let's  have these four config files in a `C:\temp\DeleteMe` directory -- and no other .xml files there:

## Config1.xml

```
<config xmlns="urn:config.template.config" >
    <exists>Yes</exists>
</config>
```

## Config2.xml

```
<config xmlns="urn:config.template.config" >
    <SomethingElse>Yes</SomethingElse>
</config>
```

## Config3.xml

```
<config xmlns="urn:config.template.config" >
    <exists>YesConfig3</exists>
</config>
```

## Config4.xml

```
<config xmlns="urn:config.template.config" >
    <SomethingElseEvenMore>Yes</SomethingElseEvenMore>
</config>
```

Do note that only Config1.xml and Config3.xml have `<exists>` element.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="my:my"
 xmlns:x="urn:config.template.config" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDirectory" as="xs:string" select="'file:///c:/temp/DeleteMe'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vConfigs" select="collection(concat($pDirectory, '?select=*.xml'))"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="my:GetConfigValue('exists', $vConfigs)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:GetConfigValue">
    <xsl:param name="pConfigName" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="pConfigs" as="document-node()*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vConfigsMatching" as="document-node()*">
       <xsl:perform-sort select="$pConfigs[*/*[name() eq $pConfigName and text()]]">
         <xsl:sort 
           select="number(substring-before(substring-after(base-uri(.), 'Config'), '.xml'))" 
           order="descending"/>
       </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:sequence select="$vConfigsMatching[1]/*/*[name() eq $pConfigName]/text()"/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied on any xml file (not used), uses as priority the number in the name of the config file -- thus the priorities from highest to lowest are:

- Config4.xml
- Config3.xml
- Config2.xml
- Config1.xml

**The transformation correctly produced the value of the config item `"exists"` from the highest-priority congfig file** (Config3.xml):

```
YesConfig3
```

**If we ask for the value of a non-existing element**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="my:GetConfigValue('not-found', $vConfigs)"/>
```

The function correctly returns the empty sequence -- the `count()` of the above is 0.

**If we remove the text-node child of `<exists>` in Config3.xml**, then correctly the function returns the string-value of `<exists>` in Config1.xml"

`Yes`

**If we also remove the text-node child of `<exists>` in Config1.xml**, then correctly the function returns no text node -- the empty sequence -- which is confirmed by the count of the resulting sequence returned as zero.

Comment: Coming from a weak xslt 1.0 background, I have many holes in my knowledge.  Trying to upgrade my game to 2.0/3.0 has been difficult. @martin did a great job at recognizing my weakness with sequences and functions.  Dimitre  has gone beyond my expectations; helping me understand file operations, types, hardening of the code, and a possible implementation.  Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you rather want to use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:value-of` e.g.

```
<xsl:sequence select="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
```

If you then do that in a named function instead of named template you can also stick to `<xsl:param name="foo" select="my:pickConfigText('arg')"/>` and your code will certainly just select the existing node or an empty sequence.

The whole issue of having the variable contain a document fragment is due to your use of `xsl:param/xsl:variable` with a nested `xsl:call-template`, without using an `as` attribute on the `xsl:param/xsl:variable` that is creating fragments.

Comment: You have definitely turned my direction around.  I'm trying to integrate the new information now!

Comment: @JackBriner I would recommend using a generalized technique for extracting values from a sequence of (prioritized) config files. This technique can be reused in any future cases you are faced with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I have ended up with a structure that is closer to what my more complex issue requires.  I have many configuration files in a directory and need to pick the appropriates by name and provide them an order.  I could have created a sequence based on those names and used that order and followed Dimitre's solution more closely.

I was also concerned a bit with performance.  My configuration files can be fairly large (and have multiple levels to the configuration).  I did not want to search multiple structures if possible; hence, I prefer my choose structure. I am not happy with have a '*' for my node selectors, but I see no other way to have a general solution.

I have also added a function (`configTextDefault1`) that may use a default value.

I have lots more to learn. Thanks to both @DimitriNovatchev and @MartinHonnen.  I still need to understand types and the processing model more completely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:myConfig="urn:config.template.config"
                xmlns:myApp="urn:my.app"
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="myConfig xs"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="primaryConfig" select="document('so.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="secondaryConfig" select="document('second.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tertiaryConfig" select="document('noExist.xml')"/>  <!-- test what happens if the file does not exist -->

    <xsl:function name="myApp:pickConfigNode1" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="level1" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]">
                <xsl:sequence select="$primaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$secondaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]">
                <xsl:sequence select="$secondaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$tertiaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]">
                <xsl:sequence select="$tertiaryConfig/myConfig:config/*[local-name() = $level1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="myApp:configText1">
        <xsl:param name="level1" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:variable name="chosenNode" select="myApp:pickConfigNode1($level1)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$chosenNode/text()"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="myApp:configTextDefault1">
        <xsl:param name="level1" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="default" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:variable name="chosenText" select="myApp:configText1($level1)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$chosenText">
                <xsl:sequence select="$chosenText"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="($default)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PRIMARY>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="myApp:configText1('primary')"><SUCCESS><xsl:value-of select="myApp:configText1('primary')"/></SUCCESS></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FAILURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'No value for primary'"/>
                    </FAILURE>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </PRIMARY>
        <SECONDARY>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="myApp:configText1('onlySecondary')"><SUCCESSS><xsl:value-of select="myApp:configText1('onlySecondary')"/></SUCCESSS></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FAILURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'No value for onlySecondary'"/>
                    </FAILURE>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </SECONDARY>
        <NEITHER>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(myApp:configText1('neither'))"><SUCCESS>NOT in any file</SUCCESS></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FAILURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Got value of for neither: '"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="myApp:configText1('neither')"/>
                    </FAILURE>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </NEITHER> 
        <DEFAULT>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="myApp:configTextDefault1('neither','default value') = 'default value'">
                    <SUCCESS><xsl:text>Got 'default value'</xsl:text></SUCCESS></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FAILURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Got wrong value: '"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="myApp:configTextDefault1('neither','default value')"/>
                    </FAILURE>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>        
        </DEFAULT>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```